# System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","classpath:file.jks") not working

Tags: spring-boot

`System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","classpath:file.jks")` not working but instead of `classpath:file.jks` if I use specific file path like `c:/file.jks` then it's working.

Answer (score 6):

```
ClassPathResource resource = new ClassPathResource("file.jks");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", Paths.get(resource.getURI()).toString());
```

Answer (score 4):

`javax.net.ssl.trustStore` is not a spring property, it is native to the Java and provided on startup to initialize `SSlContext`. Spring leverages initialized `SSLContext`. Specifying `classpath:file.jks` is spring functionality and is not part of native java; hence, this is why it does not work. If your service is a server you can set the following properties in your application properties to initialize your `SSLContext` using classpath resources with spring:

```
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:keystore.jks
server.ssl.key-store-password=pass
server.ssl.trust-store=classpath:trustStore.jks
server.ssl.trust-store-password=pass
```

This does not apply to client mode, which will need to use `javax.net.ssl.trustStore` to initialize your `SSLContext` for your Transport Layer Security.