# How to load certificate from the resources folder (and how to regenerate them)?

Tags: java, swing, keystore, truststore, tls1.3

Here is my project structure

```
src
 └── main
     ├── java
     │   └── MainClient.java
     └── resources
         └── Certificates
             ├── clientkeystore.p12
             └── clienttruststore.jks
```

I tried following approach of loading certificate

```
public class MainClient {

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        new MainClient();
    }
    public MainClient() {
        //change the image scaling for the entire application:
        System.setProperty("sun.java2d.uiScale", "1.0");
        System.setProperty("jdk.tls.client.protocols", "TLSv1.3");
        System.setProperty("jdk.tls.server.protocols", "TLSv1.3");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "Certificates/clientkeystore.p12");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "password");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "Certificates/clienttruststore.jks");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "password");
   }
}
```

this worker when Certificates folder was next to my src/ folder ,but when i moved it into resources it didn't work (**NOTE**: my resources is marked as Resources Root)

Here is my server class

```
public class MainServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // two lines below are used to set the system properties to enable TLS 1.3
        System.setProperty("jdk.tls.client.protocols", "TLSv1.3");
        System.setProperty("jdk.tls.server.protocols", "TLSv1.3");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "/home/ja/serverkeystore.p12");// /artifact/...
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "password");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "/home/ja/servertruststore.jks");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "password");
        new GreenServer(4444);
    }
}
```

Reason why i am doing all of this is because i would like to package everything inside a JAR so that certificates can be inside of it.Also  how should i regenerate them?My logic on this configuration is based on this article https://www.baeldung.com/java-https-client-certificate-authentication. This is basically two way encryption and i don;t know how should i regenerate these.

Comment: Also check other questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247746/java-loading-ssl-keystore-via-a-resource or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57605189/system-setpropertyjavax-net-ssl-truststore-classpathfile-jks-not-working

Comment: Correction: this is client _authentication_, also called two-way _authentication_ or mutual authentication, or possibly verification as your link uses in some places. It is not a change to encryption; SSL/TLS _always_ does two-way encryption even when client authentication is not used.